# How to enable RDP in a virtual machine in Azure?

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure

According the Azure policy, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/licensing-faq/, Windows Server does not need CAL licenses for a Virtual Machine running in Azure. Each time I start Windows 2012, a notification appears saying the days I have to configure the RDP license. RDP is working now because of 120 days of grace period, but I am afraid that finally, RDP will stop to work.

Am I confused? Do I need to acquire a CAL?  Or do I need to configure something?

**UPDATE:**
I am using RDP to provide access to multiple users to some applications.

Comment: Are you using rdp for administrative access only or are your remote desktop sessions for multiple users

Comment: If you read further down that same page, it also says "service providers can offer hosted solutions through RDS running on Azure as long as they obtained RDS SALs (Subscriber Access Licences) through a Microsoft Services Provider Licence Agreement (SPLA) reseller." A server CAL is not a RDS SAL. You need the latter.

Comment: Elsewhere I've read that you can use RDS CALs on Azure as long as you have Software Assurance. I'm still investigating to see if this is an option for us.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the licensing requirements are but the only way you would get that message is if you've enabled remote desktop services.  You do not need to enable remote desktop services to use an administrative remote desktop.  I would think (since Azure offers remoteapp) that there would be some type of additional license for RDS in windows server.

Comment: I needed to enable remote desktop services because I need to provide access to multiple remote users to some applications.

Comment: Administrative remote desktop only allows 2 users. After that you have to pay for RDS licensing.

Comment: @user228546 admin remote desktop isn't what's being asked about here and will not provide the error listed.

Comment: I realize it's a few years later, but for anyone reading this post-2018, RemoteApp has now been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

After your edit it appears you are misunderstanding the license in the faq. The license is referring to server CAL, which grant you rights to access the server as you would in a on site environment (This is a very basic answer but there isn't enough space here to detail MS licensing)

An RDP CAL is what is required when you wish to use RDP services to give multiple users access to a server via remote desktop as opposed to a file share for example (again basic answer). You need to purchase and install these separately. [RDP Licensing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725933.aspx)

These links explain what each is in more detail

[RDS CAL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssmallbiz/archive/2007/11/06/5942350.aspx)
[Server CAL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc725890.aspx)
[Azure RDS information](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luispanzano/2013/07/15/remote-desktop-services-are-now-allowed-on-windows-azure/)

Comment: Since it's hosted I believe it wall fall under SPLA and require a SAL - but it's been a LONG time since I've looked at Microsoft licensing- it gave me too many headaches, so best to call the vendor

Comment: It's such a minefield

Comment: I wouldn't say minefield- it's not oracle, it's just complicated.  once you know what _your_ licensing situation is, it's not that bad. it's trying to figure out someone elses OR trying to figure it out without Microsoft that's hard

Comment: Also, you need to purchase the CALs with Software Assurance to use them on an Azure VM.

Comment: @user228546 actually that isn't 100% accurate. If you want to use existing volume license CALs on your azure deployment you have to have software assurance.

Comment: What is the other alternative? Are you saying you don't need SA if you purchase new CALs?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I'm pretty sure that you require additional Win Server RDS CALs if you have a guest configured as a Remote Desktop Services host (multiple user sessions or terminal server type setup).

Deploying Win Server on a VM inside Azure without RD services doesn't require additional CALs and you'll get standard server CALs included as part of the license agreement within Azure.

If you're continuing with RD Services moving forward, then you'll need to install the RDS CALs onto a RDS license server and make that available/point your RDS host off to it. There is nothing different with setting up a basic RDS host in Azure compared to doing it on premise.

Answer (score 0):

RDP is your only way to access your VM so it shouldn't one day lock you out.  If I remember correctly, the CAL licenses are required for when you want to allow multiple users to login (rather than just an admin).

Comment: Yes, by default you can have two admins access the VM concurrently (there is an "admin" setting in the RDP config file). If you want additional users to access the VM you have to get RDS licenses (either SALs or CALs with software assurance).